# overflow issue with jquery resizable handle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

i am adding resizable functionality to an image using jquery resizable,and its working fine. I want to show the handles but there is an issue while showing the handles.

As in the image below

[image]

handles are not completely visible, what can i do so that handles are completely visible, an example can be seen in this fiddle

example fiddle code

```
<div id='elementResizable'>
<h1>Full Name</h1>
Title
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" id="nwgrip"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" id="negrip"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" id="swgrip"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se" id="segrip"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/digitalaxis/j2JU6/ and handles are also not completely visible.

Comment: why this question is down voted, even it has an answer that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jsfiddle code , from CSS in #elementResizable remove overflow :hidden and check , it will works.